# How to create and attach a new disk to an existing Windows Virtual Machine using ARM template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-machine

I have already created VM in my resource group Now I want to add a new Data Disk to my existing VM so Can someone provide me any GitHub URL template link which I can refer to for this requirement. Below Link, I have already gone.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/using-managed-disks-template-deployments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new data disk and append to a new created VM by ARM template, try the template below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vmName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "diskName": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [{
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {

                "storageProfile": {
                    "dataDisks": [{
                            "lun": 0,
                            "name": "[parameters('diskName')]",
                            "createOption": "attach",
                            "managedDisk": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/', parameters('diskName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/', parameters('diskName'))]"]
        }, {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/disks",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('diskName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "properties": {
                "creationData": {
                    "createOption": "Empty"
                },
                "diskSizeGB": 1023
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

I use PowerShell to deploy. Result:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

If your VM has 1 data disk already, you want to keep it and append a new data disk to it, you need specify both of this 2 disks in `dataDisks`, for a quick test, the template below is based on the previous one: This vm has been appended a disk : `test6-disk` and append a new one and keep them two:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vmName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "diskName": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [{
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {

                "storageProfile": {
                    "dataDisks": [{
                            "lun": 0,
                            "name": "test6-disk",
                            "createOption": "attach",
                            "managedDisk": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/','test6-disk')]"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "lun": 1,
                            "name": "[parameters('diskName')]",
                            "createOption": "attach",
                            "managedDisk": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/', parameters('diskName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/', parameters('diskName'))]"]
        }, {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/disks",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('diskName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "properties": {
                "creationData": {
                    "createOption": "Empty"
                },
                "diskSizeGB": 1023
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

Result:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply I am trying to run from Custom deployment azure portal and getting below error "Changing property 'dataDisk.managedDisk.id' is not allowed."

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya, this issue is due to vm has been appended a data disk already and occupied lun 0 solt. Please change resources => properties=>storageProfile=>dataDisks=>lun from 0 to 1 and try again (if you appended 2 data disks ,change lun to 2) for more about lun, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/azure-to-guest-disk-mapping?tabs=azure-cli#what-is-a-lun

Comment: Thank you for the comments Yes, I changed that LUN  and It worked for me but problem is whenever I am trying to add new DataDisk Previuos one automatically removed (Dettach ) so can you please help me on this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya, glad to know that it is helpful. Yes, I can totally understand it, once you use this way to append a new disk, Azure will update your VM as your template defined, in my demo template, there is only 1 disk,your previous disk will be removed as you have not defined it in dataDisks. So if you want to append a new disk and keep the previous one, you should also define the previous disk in resources => properties=>storageProfile=>dataDisks .

Comment: Thank you again for reply Can you please send me ARM template with previous disk details .

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya,sure , I have appended an update,pls accept it as an answer if it solves your issue : )

Comment: Thank you Yes I also done in same way but I don't think this is good idea because suppose in my VM there are 10 already disk attached and i need to add one more so i need to write 10 resources  for disk right ? I think we need to do like array Is there any way we can do like this and do loop? but thank you for the cooperating me thanks once again.

Comment: You are right, and this is the only way I know to do this by template . Actually, using a template to do this is not so easy, personally, I prefer to use API or SDK

Comment: Ok no problem Thanks once again for clarification

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya, welcome .Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : )

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow so don't have  above15 reputation point

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya, thanks for your mark on time :)